# Ionic : Autofocus a text field

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

i know this question has been asked many times but i was unable to find my solution:

i am trying to atuofocus a text field on page load as below :

**Html:**

```
<input type="text" #autofocusfield>
```

**TS File**

Related import

```
import { Component,ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
```

Code to auto focus :

```
export class Tab1Page {
  @ViewChild('autofocusfield') inputtext; 

ionViewDidLoad() {         
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.inputtext.setFocus();
    }, 500);
  }
```

i also tried to use autofocus='true' but that did not work , Can someone please guide me how can i achieve this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is all you need simply. demo in this [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-nln6wa?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

```
@ViewChild("autoFocus") private af: ElementRef;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {}
ngAfterViewChecked() {
  this.af.nativeElement.focus();
}
```

You only need focus() method to set inside ngAfterViewChecked() hook.

Template of HTML is..

```
<input #autoFocus type="text" >
```

Comment: can i also do it using ion-input to collec the onchange value of the field ?

Comment: Please see https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/input, you just need to put autofocus or [autofocus]="true". The component has its prebuilt input properties or you can do it by using @ViewChild inside the controller